# Quickly switch between buffers?

Tags: vim

I have a lot of buffers open and to switch between then I `Ctrl+w` and then `Ctrl+[movement key]`. Is there a better way? Because this way when I've to do more than one movement I end up having to press 4 keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to move between *windows*, you always can map `Ctrl-W, H/J/K/L` to anything you want:

```
map <C-h> <C-w>h
map <C-j> <C-w>j
map <C-k> <C-w>k
map <C-l> <C-w>l
```

If you want to move between *buffers*, you can use `:buffer` command, print a part of the file name you want to go to: pressing `Tab` will cycle through all files that contains this part in the names. E.g you want to show buffer with filename 'some_long_c_file.c' and you know you don't have any other opened file whose name ends with 'file.c': just type `:buffer file.c` and press `Tab` (or even 'ile.c' or shorter), this will complete it to 'some_long_c_file.c'.

For quick switching between the two last buffers, use `Ctrl-^`

Comment: I love the `Ctrl-^`, I was hitting `Ctrl-w` twice. You're a hero!

Comment: wow. ctrl-^ just changed my life. Don't understand why/how I didn't find that before. thx

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to do this is to install [`bufexplorer.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42). That let's you quickly switch to a screen in which you can select any buffer.  You can also close buffers etc..

Here's a screenshot of my vim with bufexplorer open showing it's help screen:

[image]

Comment: I am using bufexplorer myself, but I find it kinda slow. It takes a few seconds to open the explorer buffer and it is really noticeable.

Comment: @XavierT. Interesting, I've always found it very speedy, almost instant even with huge numbers of files.

Comment: @XavierT. That perceived slowness may be due to another mapping that starts with the same keys; Vim then has to wait for the timeout.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat : Good idea, I will check that.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was two-fold:

1) Use [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) - so `]b` and `[b`

2) map `:b#` to switch to previous buffer. I used `map <cr> :b#<cr>` . (so enter key would toggle back and forth between two open buffers).